# Find text within line item, add corresponding ID to that line item

Tags: jquery, replace, each

I am trying to write JQuery to grab the contents of an list item (LI) within a specific ID, and for each LI, add an ID equal to the text within the LI.

So in other words make each LI addressable in CSS using its own text content as an ID. I am not the best at JQuery as you may guess, so unsure of the next steps. I got so far as below with the HTML/JQuery.

Ideally it would ignore the first LI, replace spaces and any special characters with a hyphen.

HTML:

```
<div id="services">
   <div class="box">
        <ul>
            <li><button type="button">CLOSE</button></li>
            <li>Irrigation</li>
            <li>Transport</li>
            <li>Construction</li>
            <li>Import & distribution</li>
            <li>Iwi</li>
            <li>Tourism</li>
            <li>Logistics</li>
            <li>Education</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $( "#services .box li" ).each(function( index ) { //for each relevant LI on the page...
      //if not the first LI / not containing a <button>, then...
      var one_id = $(this).text();
      one_id = one_id.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'-');
      $(this).attr('id', one_id);
   });
})
```

Comment: Note that there are multiple UL elements of this type within the <div id="services"><div class="box"></div></div>

Comment: I don't really understand. Why cant you just simply use $(this).attr('class', one_id);, and then add a class with that name in css?

Comment: A class would be fine too, but unsure how to make the above code actually function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can exclude any that have a button or are first child using `not()` and trim out the extra `-` when you get multiples

Something like:

```js
$("#services .box li").not(':has(button),:first-child').each(function() {
  var one_id = $(this).text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '-').replace(/-+/g, '-');
  $(this).attr('id', one_id).append(' => ID: ' + one_id);// remove append in production
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="services">
  <div class="box">
    <ul>
      <li><button type="button">CLOSE</button></li>
      <li>Irrigation</li>
      <li>Transport</li>
      <li>Construction</li>
      <li>Import & distribution</li>
      <li>Iwi</li>
      <li>Tourism</li>
      <li>Logistics</li>
      <li>Education</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds good, albeit not currently doing what it's meant to. I tried implementing this and it doesn't throw an error, nor apply the ID to the LIs.

Comment: It does in snippet above when you run it. Something must be different. Did you wrap it in jQuery(function($){ })`? I left that out since not needed above

Comment: Selector wrong. Specify the ul element before the element li.

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz That's simply a matter of opionion ... the <li> can't exist without a <ul> or <ol>

Comment: You were right, @charlietfl - an incorrect ID used. Working now, thanks all. I'd mark up but as I noob my vote doesn't really count.

Answer (score 0):

This code is already doing what you want to do. [eq selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) that you needed to select the first or other ul element.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $( "div.box > ul:eq(0) > li:not(:first)" ).each(function( index ) { 
      $(this).attr('id', $(this).text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'-'));
   });
})
```

Comment: This looks promising and works for the first UL on the page. I was guessing at how to use the "each" method as there are multiple ULs on the page requiring this to be executed. Is there a means of applying it at the higher level so it works on all?